# jquery simple sliding animation

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, slidetoggle

....maybe not so simple.

First, I am trying to code this in Wordpress, not sure if that has anything to do with it. I want the blog page to show a title for all of the blogs. Then when the user clicks on the blog title the content slides down. The HTML will look like this.

```
<div id="titel>Title of Post</div>
<div id="meta">Meta data WP adds</div>
<div id="entry">The content of the blog post.</div>
```

I use a function in the functions.php to autamtically reference jQuery on Google. I'm ussing CSS to hide #entry.

Now when I add my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $j=jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(document).ready(function(){

        $j('#title').click(function(){
            $j(this).next('#entry').slideToggle('1000');

        });


    });

</script>
```

nothing happens. You can click the title but no content. But oddly enough, if you change the code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $j=jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(document).ready(function(){

        $j('#title').click(function(){
            $j('#entry').slideToggle('1000');

        });


    });

</script>
```

the very first post will get the animation. But shouldn't it be that (using this second code) that if ANY of the titles are clicked ALL of the #entry are slid down? That is the part that is really throwing my for a loop.

Thanks for all the responses. Here is the exact code as it stands. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="article-title"> <h2 class="entry-title"><a  title="Permalink to Similarities" rel="bookmark">Similarities</a></h2></div>

<div class="entry-content"><div class="article-entry"><p><span style="font-size: small;"> HERE IS THE BLOG CONTENT.....
```

and here is the code as I have it now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $j=jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $('.article-title').click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.entry-content').slideToggle(1000);
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: ID's are unique, it will only find the first one, use classes instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fusuv/3/ id has wrong spelling bro, not sure who down voted below, care to reply please anyhooo, cheers!

Comment: I downvoted, the answer is'nt that `$j` is wrong and should be replaced with just `$`, as he's using jQeury in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, read the docs.

Comment: @adeneo <is that so mate> so I was just making it clear that why not keep it simple and use `$` instead of `$j` anyhow man take it easy mate! great that you read the docs! cheers!

Comment: Well that's great, but if there is another script on his page already using `$` for something else, there will be a conflict, hence the noConflict method ?

Comment: @adeneo your right, I did that to keep any potential conflicts with future plugins.

Comment: and a big DOH on my part for the ID's..... thanks for pointing that out. Also thanks for point outthe misspelling, but that's just something I typed in for here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem: ID's are unique. There should be only one element per ID.

Second problem: You messed up the name of the ID:

```
<div id="titel">Title of Post</div>
```

and

```
$j('#title').click(function(){
```

(titel != title)

Third problem: jQuerys `next()` function accesses the next element, which would be the Meta data in your case.

---

Try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="title">Title of Post</div>
    <div class="meta">Meta data WP adds</div>
    <div class="entry">The content of the blog post.</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j=jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.title').click(function(){
            $j(this).siblings('.entry').slideToggle('1000');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.entry{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I changed the ID to Classes and used the sibling selector but still won't work. ??

Comment: What happens when you click the title? Nothing?

Comment: Strange, it should be working. What browser are you using? Can you show us your entire code or give us an URL to your site?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Site is on my laptop, but I'll copy the code:

Comment: You mixed `$j` and `$` in your JavaScript. If you want to use jQuery in no-conflict mode, you have to keep using `$j`. Change `$` in your code to `$j`.

Comment: oh, for the love of...... Thank you so much. I think I just earned the award for most idiotic mistakes today.. :-D

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider that there should be only 1 element with certain ID on the page. So make sure that all blog entry elements have classes or unique IDs at least. Here is one option:

```
<div class="title">Title of Post</div>
<div class="meta">Meta data WP adds</div>
<div class="entry">The content of the blog post.</div>
```

Then, you use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method which:

> Gets the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements.

Whereas your next element is `meta` block. You can use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method to address `entry`.

```
$j('.title').click(function(){
    $j(this).siblings('.entry').slideToggle('1000');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the workings of siblings() and next() backwards in my head. I tried to use the siblings selector but it still won't work (also made the ID into Classes. )

Answer (score 0):

first use class for elements that is more than 1 in content .
you can also use parents in jquery.

```
<div>
  <div class="title">Title of Post</div>
  <div class="meta">Meta data WP adds</div>
  <div class="entry">The content of the blog post.</div>
</div>

$j('.title').click(function(){
   $j(this).parents('div').find('.entry').slideToggle('1000');
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I click the title all of the articles open.